# Basecamp 3 Automatic Check-ins API?

Tags: basecamp

I don't see an obvious way to integrate w/ the [Check-ins section](http://d.pr/i/1ag1U) of Basecamp 3 via [API](https://github.com/basecamp/bcx-api). Is there one?

Answer (score 1):

There are now three versions of Basecamp.  Classic, Basecamp2, and now Basecamp3 (introduced in the fall of 2015).  The Check-ins feature is part of Basecamp3.  The API documentation you referenced is for Basecamp2.  Here is the latest from Basecamp on Twitter:

[@fritzsbm](https://twitter.com/fritzsbm) There aren't any integrations at the moment. Sorry! We're working on getting the API ready for release. :)— Basecamp (@basecamp) [December 9, 2015](https://twitter.com/basecamp/status/674726690267004930)